# Validate ng-pattern in Angular unit test

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I have the following piece of HTML which is loaded dynamically with a switch case. There was no need to create separate directives for this, therefore we decided to do it this way.

```
<li ng-form="form">
    <input name="number" type="number" ng-model="selectedCriterion.valueFrom" ng-pattern="selectedCriterion.regexPattern">
</li>
```

with the following unit test

```
describe('form', function() {
    rootScope.selectedCriterion = { regexPattern: '[0-5]+' };

    it('allows numbers to be filled in the input field', function() {
        var compiledElement = $compile(html)(rootScope);
        rootScope.$apply();     
        var form = rootScope.form;
        var inputElement = compiledElement.find('input[name="number"]');

        inputElement.val(4).triggerHandler('input');
        rootScope.$digest();

        expect(inputElement.val()).toEqual('4');
        expect(form.$valid).toEqual(true);

        inputElement.val(8).triggerHandler('input');
        rootScope.$digest();

        expect(inputElement.val()).toEqual('8');
        expect(form.$valid).toEqual(false);
    });
});
```

What I would like to do is test the ng-pattern in a unit test, not in on e2e test level.
The test fails at the last expectation

```
expect(form.$valid).toEqual(false);
```

It seems that the form cannot validate itself on this level, even though I compile my HTML and call a $digest cycle manually.

What am I doing wrong? Can I validate the form on this level?

Edit: I have intensively searched StackOverflow and Google for answers without success.

Comment: You need to give more information (e.g. which expectation fails, is this html inside a directive, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem.
Like vbuhlev said, my code worked, but the reason it did not for me in the first place was because I had an extra attribute on my input element that I did not put in the initial post because I thought it was not important.
My actual input element had a debounce option:

```
<input name="number" type="number" ng-model="selectedCriterion.valueFrom" ng-pattern="selectedCriterion.regexPattern" ng-model-options="{debounce: 200}" >
```

Karma did not take this into account by default, saw that my form was "valid" without waiting for the debounce to finish and just went on.
I solved this by flushing any tasks that were still pending with

```
$timeout.flush()
```

This immediately executes the debounce before checking the validity of the form.

It now runs really smooth!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct!

I have tried your test in isolation and it works. Essentially it is the same as yours.

```
'use strict';

describe('form', function() {

    it('allows numbers to be filled in the input field', inject(function($compile, $rootScope) {
        var html = '<li ng-form="form">'
            + '<input name="number" type="number" ng-model="selectedCriterion.valueFrom" ng-pattern="selectedCriterion.regexPattern">'
            + '</li>';

        $rootScope.selectedCriterion = { regexPattern: '[0-5]+' };
        var rootScope = $rootScope;

        var compiledElement = $compile(html)(rootScope);
        rootScope.$apply();     
        var form = rootScope.form;
        var inputElement = compiledElement.find('input[name="number"]');

        inputElement.val(4).triggerHandler('input');
        rootScope.$digest();

        expect(inputElement.val()).toEqual('4');
        expect(form.$valid).toEqual(true);

        inputElement.val(8).triggerHandler('input');
        rootScope.$digest();

        expect(inputElement.val()).toEqual('8');
        expect(form.$valid).toEqual(false);
    }));
});
```

You have some other code which is breaking things. You need to give more context.